# Finding last integer and returning variable name

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to return both the value and the state which each value belongs to.

So I currently have these states encased in a function

```
obs = random.uniform(0,1)
func = lambda x: x if x > random.uniform(0,1) else False
a_to_b = func(obs) 
b_to_c = func(a_to_b)
c_to_d = func(b_to_c)
```

If I simply return the values from each variable I will only get the figure and not the state associated with the figure.

My desired output is if the last number is in state b_to_c I would like to return the number along with the name of the state

Comment: What is the (name of the) state here?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem the name of the state is the name of the variable so e.g a_to_b

Comment: But a variable has no name so to speak, it is only an identifier. Say you would call it with `func(1+1)`, then there is even no variable at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your very simple example, you can solve it with a dictionary;

```
results = dict(a2b=func(obs))
results['b2c']=func(results['a2b'])
results['c2d']=func(results['b2c'])

for key,val in results.items():
    print(key,val)
```